# How do I change the font size when using lp on Linux?

Tags: linux, printing, fonts

I used to send files in Unix to a printer with `lp`, and used `-ofp16.16` or `-ofp12` to change the size of the fonts. This does not work on Linux; what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3):

This is more a matter of what is behind `lp` and (possibly) of the printer drivers. If you're running the `CUPS`, there are [some options to change characters per inch and columns per inch](http://localhost:631/help/options.html#TEXTOPTIONS) (local URL, works if you have `CUPS` running and it was installed with documentation).

Now I'd guess "fp" stood for "font points" or something like that, which `CUPS` does not seem to have, at least by default (but I'd not be surprised if there were hidden options somewhere).

This is also more of a document preparation issue — I agree it'd be awesome if the printing system was able to do all the magic we need with stuff we want to print, but maybe it's worth looking at, e.g., `a2ps`, a plain text to postscript typesetter, which has a `--font-size=...` option (by default it outputs a two-column file, I usually use `-1` to do 1 column per page, but if that conflicts with `--font-size`, have a look at `--columns`).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try `enscript`, which formats text as PostScript.

Enscript may come pre-installed with your distro otherwise you'll have to install it from whatever software repository you use. The `-F` option allows you to specify font and font size, e.g.

```
enscript -FCourier12 myfiletoprint.txt
```

Enscript should print to your default printer. If not, you will have to specify the print queue using `-d` (mnemonic: destination).

```
enscript -FCourier12 myfiletoprint.txt -d KONICA-MINOLTA-C652-Series
```

As a bonus, if you have the cups pdf driver installed, this is a very quick way to create pdf files.